# Django un Azure Webapp: Run command on deployment

Tags: django, azure, deployment, web-applications, command

I am deploying a Django app to Azure Webapp, which does everything automatically. I have set it up so when I push to a specific Github branch, it is deployed and everything works. If I have to run a migration, I must login via SSH and run it manually (which is not perfect but I can accept it).

However, I need to use django-background-tasks, which needs to have a command running constantly listen for new tasks. I can't find a way to run this on every deployment. I found some documentation but most of it is for Node apps, it seems. For example, following some (oudated) tutoriales, I logged into {myapp}.scm.azurewebsites.net but I didnt find any "Download deployment scripts", which it seemed to be the proper way to do it.

Is there a way to set up some commands to run on deployment (without changing my current setup of deploy directly from Github using Github actions)? Or I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if someone is looking how to do it, I found the solution.

Create a startup file (sh), add the first line the gunicorn instruction and after that your own custom commands.

Here is explained: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-04#create-a-startup-file